# Trying to create first react native app getting Build Failed error

Tags: android, react-native

Trying to create my first App.

Getting this error refereed tried with some commends unable to install app.

can any one please tell me what is going wrong.

Comment: image path: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fu0Ke.png

Answer (score 0):

Try running `./gradlew` tasks before running `react-native run-android`.